# Вставить из базы данных в Listview только определенные данные?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget, qtableview, qtsql

Всем привет. Получается мне нужно сделать итерацию по базе данных, и вывести в `listWidget` только тех людей, у которых до истечения даты остается менее 45 дней.

В **`3`** столбце как раз вставляется **`дата`** в формате (`10-10-2022` пример).

Делал простейшую программу с `listWidget`, но там я работал с экселем, это намного проще, а как с БД, не получается.

Вот пример как с экселем делал(часть кода)

```
import csv
import datetime
today_date = datetime.date.today()
for row in csv.reader(open('Disp_data2.csv'), delimiter=';'):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%d-%m-%Y")
    quantity_days = date.date() - today_date
    imya = row[0]
    if quantity_days.days < 45:
        disp = str(imya) + ' ' + str(quantity_days)
        text = "Нажмите, чтобы отправить смс"
        listWidget.addItem(f'{disp} {text}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.Qt import *


'''
conn = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists disp_list(disp_name text, disp_surname text, disp_date text)')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
'''


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 435)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 170, 341, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 331, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")


#        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: 
#        self.add_disp())

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 350, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 30, 350, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 591, 301))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        item.setFont(font)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(180)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 10, 251, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Список диспетчеров, у которых заканчивается срок"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add ATC"))

        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete from database"))


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_name = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_surname = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_date = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('Name:', self.line_edit_name)
        form_layout.addRow('Surname:', self.line_edit_surname)
        form_layout.addRow('Date:', self.line_edit_date)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        font = self.pushButton.font()
        self.btn_dispatchers = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Список диспетчеров')
        self.btn_dispatchers.setFont(font)
        
        main_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0)        
        main_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 0, 1) 
        main_layout.addWidget(self.btn_dispatchers, 0, 3) 
        
        main_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 5, 2) 
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 2, 1, 2) 
        main_layout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 2, 2, 4, 2) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_disp)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.delete_disp)
# +++ 
        self.btn_dispatchers.clicked.connect(self.dispatchers_term_ends)    # +++ 


        # 1. Создайте соединение с базой данных, вызвав метод addDatabase() класса QSqlDatabase.
        #    Так как вы хотите соединиться с базой данных SQLite, параметры QSQLITE передаются здесь.
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')

        # 2. Вызовите setDatabaseName(), чтобы установить имя базы данных, 
        # которое будет использоваться.
        #    Вам нужно только написать путь, а имя файла заканчивается на .db
        #   (если база данных уже существует, используйте базу данных; если она не существует,
        #    будет создана новая);
        db.setDatabaseName('todo.db')

        # 3. Вызовите метод open(), чтобы открыть базу данных.
        #    Если открытие прошло успешно, оно вернет True, а в случае неудачи - False.
        db.open()

        # Создайте модель QSqlTableModel и вызовите setTable(),
        # чтобы выбрать таблицу данных для обработки.
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("disp_list")  # !!! тавлица в db

        # вызовите метод select(), чтобы выбрать все данные в таблице, и соответствующее
        # представление также отобразит все данные;
        self.model.select()
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def dispatchers_term_ends(self): 
        rows = self.model.rowCount()                     
        if not rows:
            return
            
        self.listWidget.clear()
        
        for row in range(rows):
            name = self.model.record(row).value("disp_name")
            surname = self.model.record(row).value("disp_surname")
            date = self.model.record(row).value("disp_date")
            
            now = QDate.currentDate()
            qdate = QtCore.QDate.fromString(date, "dd-MM-yyyy")
            
            days = now.daysTo(qdate)
            if days < 45:
                self.listWidget.addItem(f"{name}; {surname}; {date}")
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def add_disp(self):
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return
        name = inputDialog.line_edit_name.text()
        surname = inputDialog.line_edit_surname.text()
        date = inputDialog.line_edit_date.text()
        if not name or not surname or not date:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните пожалуйста все поля.')
            return

        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue("disp_name", name)
        r.setValue("disp_surname", surname)
        r.setValue("disp_date", date)
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
        self.model.select()

    # Удалить запись   
    def delete_disp(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentIndex().row()
        if row == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Выберите запись для удаления.')
            return    

        name = self.model.record(row).value(1)
        surname = self.model.record(row).value(2)
        date = self.model.record(row).value(3)
        
        inputDialog = Dialog()
        inputDialog.setWindowTitle('Удалить запись ???')
        inputDialog.line_edit_name.setText(name)
        inputDialog.line_edit_surname.setText(surname)
        inputDialog.line_edit_date.setText(date)       
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return  

        self.model.removeRow(self.tableWidget.currentIndex().row())    
        self.model.select()                                         
        
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Успех', 'Запись удалена.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! супер